# Heroku node app 404 not found, doesn't load front end js files or css

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, heroku, http-status-code-404

So I have a simple application that works fine on localhost, but when I deploy it to Heroku, the front end files don't load, so i get my raw html with no style or functionality. The browser directory is where all of the files that don't load are located. I'm going to put my server file and package.json below. I really appreciate any help. Thanks!

server.js

```
const path = require('path');

    const http = require('http');
    const server = http.createServer();

    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();

    server.on('request', app);

    server.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000)

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'Browser')));

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'chess.html'));
    });
```

package.JSON

```
{
      "name": "Chess",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "One player chess against an AI",
      "main": "server.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node server.js"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=4.0.0"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "express": ">=4.13.3"
      }
    }
```

File Structure

```
_Chessjs
+-- app.json
+-- package.json
+-- Procfile
+-- chess.html
+-- server.js
+-- _Broswer
|   +-- ai.js
|   +-- board.js
|   +-- game.js
|   +-- piece.js
|   +-- style.css
+-- _node_modules
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you add the following to your scripts in package.json:

"heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install --only=dev && npm install && npm run build"

Or else you'll probably still have these error messages even after fixing any problems
with your MERN App.

More Info at the following Link: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/issues/589